# How to extract the text displayed in a dot matrix LED display

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, python-tesseract

I need to extract the number from a display(LED dot matrix)
[image: my image for text extraction]

Sample Image:
[image: dot matrix display]

I am using the example code given by pytesseract to test. But I am failing.

```py
try:
    from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
    import Image
import pytesseract

# If you don't have tesseract executable in your PATH, include the following:
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'<full_path_to_your_tesseract_executable>'
# Example tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'

# Simple image to string
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test.png')))
```

From the sample image I need the output as the number and alphabets given.

If my image have only one number totally filled in whole display that number alone should be in result..  Am I using the right tools? or should I look into opencv and machine learning to extract characters from display.

Comment: Perhaps this will help. Not exactly the same. But you might adapt it. https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/13/recognizing-digits-with-opencv-and-python/

Comment: @fmw42 I will try as the post guided for dot matrix.